Visual Studio 2008 - can't view project properties because Can't load Windows Form Designer Package?
I still have a need to use VS2008 for a specific non-windows target.  It's worked fine and I can still compile fine, but all of a sudden when trying to view properties of a project it says:
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Package Load Failure

Package 'Windows Forms Designer Package' has failed to load properly ( GUID = {7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF} ). Please contact package vendor for assistance. Application restart is recommended, due to possible environment corruption. Would you like to disable loading this package in the future? You may use 'devenv /resetskippkgs' to re-enable package loading.
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------

Then, after closing the message you get:
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Failed to create .NET Frameworks PropertyGrid component.
Please verify that the Common Language Runtime and .NET Frameworks are properly installed.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

There is no project properties showing up, just a blank grey area where it would go.
I started vs2008 with /log and this is what that says:
<entry>
    <record>136</record>
    <time>2024/04/07 08:13:44.693</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [Windows Forms Designer Package]</description>
    <guid>{7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>137</record>
    <time>2024/04/07 08:13:44.696</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio</source>
    <description>CreateInstance failed for package [Windows Forms Designer Package]</description>
    <guid>{7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}</guid>
    <hr>80131604</hr>
    <errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>138</record>
    <time>2024/04/07 08:13:44.696</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft Visual Studio</source>
    <description>End package load [Windows Forms Designer Package]</description>
    <guid>{7494682B-37A0-11D2-A273-00C04F8EF4FF}</guid>
    <hr>80004005 - E_FAIL</hr>
    <errorinfo>Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.</errorinfo>
  </entry>

I tried devenv /resetskippkgs but that didn't help.
I ran sfc /scannow and it said it repaired something but didn't fix this.
I ran the dot net repair tool, that didn't help.
Any idea on how to fix this?
TIA!!
